# ofstream keeps giving me the last line of the function instead of showng everything

Tags: c++, ofstream

so I have been trying to figure out a way to have a function enter whatever is written in a file and to output into a Sha-256 function. maybe why do I want to do that? Simple enough I am trying to just teach myself how things work in c++, however it displays the last line for the function ofstream. this is my main function

```
ifstream input ("/home/findme/Desktop/text.txt"); // opens text.txt file.
string s;
while (getline (input, s))
{ 
    // loop to read every line one by one of the file.
    string c = s;               // enters function to be converted.
    string output1 = sha256(c); // gives back the value of the string.
    cout << "sha256('"<< c << "'):" << output1 << endl; //displays the results.   
    ofstream outfile ("/home/findme/Desktop/result.txt");
    outfile << "sha256('"<< c << "'):" << output1 << endl; 
    outfile.close();
}
```

ok so just an insight of what happens, it reads the context of the file named text.txt in this file there is 3 lines which are (test, test2, test3). so it reads one line and sends it to the function and it returns then it does it for the second line and so on. Once it hits the last line the cout function reads this

sha256('test'):9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08

sha256('test2'):60303ae22b998861bce3b28f33eec1be758a213c86c93c076dbe9f558c11c752

sha256('test3'):fd61a03af4f77d870fc21e05e7e80678095c92d808cfb3b5c279ee04c74aca13

and that's correct. there is no problem whatsoever with the cout function but when I try to put it in an external file named result.txt it displays

sha256('test3'):fd61a03af4f77d870fc21e05e7e80678095c92d808cfb3b5c279ee04c74aca13

That's is the problem, it seems like all it does is writes the last function. I tried to change the placing of the ofstream as in outside the loop or before the cout function and it gives the same issue, I also tried with a loop and it gives the same issue. It just repeats the sha256('test3').

Now I know that its obviously something really easy to fix but im not seeing, therefore can someone please help me? I want it to display exactlty what the cout displays. (there are no error messages and it compiles without a problem). Thank you

Comment: Please format your code and punctuate your text.

Comment: @NeilButterworth ok, done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating your `ofstream outfile` in the loop. Meaning it's recreated each iteration through the loop. If you move this line to the top of your sample code it should work:

```
ofstream outfile ("/home/findme/Desktop/result.txt");
```

Comment: Omg that's correct... Stupid me didn't even see that.. thank you so much

Comment: No prob, sometimes all you need is another set of eyes. If this solved your problem please don't forget to accept.